# Attach ASG from Beanstalk to TargetGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template that creates an `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` and an  `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup`

I would like to associate the `AutoScalingGroup` that beanstalk creates with the `TargetGroup` created in my template.

My end goal is doing path-based routing via an ALB to a bunch of beanstalk applications from a single domain (i.e., `www.domain.com/foo` routes to `ebapp1` and `www.domain.com/bar` routes to `ebapp2`)

I can actually accomplish what I wish via the CLI:

```
aws autoscaling attach-load-balancer-target-groups --auto-scaling-group-name "<asg-name>" --target-group-arns "<arn-for-target-group>"
```

However, I would like to have this association created automatically when I launch my new beanstalk environment via CloudFormation.

I am having trouble figuring out how to translate this into my CloudFormation template. Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

Your CLI command is related to `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`, and if you want to get result as same as your CLI command you can use `TargetGroupARNs` parameter on `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup.`
Use the Reference function to get the value of target group arn parameter.

If this is not what you need, and if your command really works, you can call it using `UserData` or `metadata` in an instance that you have created on your template to run your CLI command.